# Top 5 Items in Table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given the following data:

[image: dataset]

I would like to get the top 5 results from the table. I tried the following formulas:

Measure: `Violation Ranking = RANKX(ALL(Violation_Data), COUNTA(Violation_Data[Violation]))`

Column: `Top Violations = IF([Violation Ranking] > 5, "Others", Violation_Data[Violation])`

But I'm still getting all of the results from [Violation] (I think it has something to do with the Calculated Column). I tried using a Visual Filter instead (show only [Violation Ranking] <= 5), but I'm still getting the same results (the [Violation Ranking] of each [Violation] is 1 (which is odd, to say the least) that's why all of the violations are displayed.

Anyone know how to correct the given DAX code?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

In the 'Modeling' tab, click 'New Table'...

[image]

Then use TOPN and GROUPBY, like this:

```
Violation_Counts = TOPN(5,GROUPBY(Violation_Data,Violation_Data[Violation],"Count",countx(CURRENTGROUP(),Violation_Data[Name])))
```

...which will give you a new table of the Top 5 Violations, like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I got it. I was able to use Visual Filters to select just the top 5 most recurrent Violations in the table like so:

[image: visual filter]